# Java projects with gpdraw imported cannot be run on intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to run a program which uses the gpdraw library in intelliJ but each time I try to run the program, intelliJ asks me for a configuration. Eg: Java Applet, Java Application, Ant etc. I wanted to know why this was happening and how I could fix it. I'm fairly new to intelliJ since I've been using BlueJ forever. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks